# UL tag inside gridster widget

Tags: javascript, gridster

I'm trying to use `ul` tag inside gridster widget but for some reason list is not working correctly.

Please see fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/h9f63/237/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you've enabled gridster inside of gridster.

On line 5 of your JavaScript, you select all `ul` tags inside your gridster and turn them into sub-gridsters.  You can change that to only select the outer `ul` element by using a greater-than sign, like this:

```
    gridster = $(".gridster > ul").gridster({  //...
```

The addition of this `>` sign makes the selector target only the one `ul` that is the direct descendant of `.gridster`, not all the `ul`s contained within.

Likewise, your CSS needs the same fix:

```
.gridster > ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: gray;
}
.gridster > ul li {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Try it with those changes, it should work much better.